# Generic circular bitwise shift behavior

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

There are bunch of questions on circular bitwise shift behavior over here; however, even after going through them, I don't think the statement below is being raised by anyone and I am kind of confused with regard to it.

Statement on [Circular Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) from Wikipedia:

> ```
> /*
>  * Shift operations in C are only defined for shift values which are
>  * not negative and smaller than sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT.
>  */
>
> unsigned int rotl(unsigned int value, int shift) {
>     return (value << shift) | (value >> (sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT - shift));
> }
>
> unsigned int rotr(unsigned int value, int shift) {
>     return (value >> shift) | (value << (sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT - shift));
> }
> ```

My interpretation of above lines is — in above mentioned two conditions of shift behavior would be undefined.

However I see examples given

`rotl(0x8000, -1)` with answer `0x00010000`.

`rotl(8,-1)` with answer `16`.

What is the right way to deal with such shift parameters (i.e. negative and greater than number of bits)? Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: The second example contradicts the first example. I think that the result of the second function call should be 16 instead of 4.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - Yes I edited the answer - but I have put the examples for reference - my main point of confusion is the part - according to which if shift value is -ve - behavior should be undefined - Can you help me understand it ?

Comment: If you do a right shift (`>>`), the value on the RHS must be between 0 and the number of bits in the value minus one; if you do a left shift, the value on the RHS must be between 0 and the number of bits in the value minus one.  Therefore, you can define one direction as positive and the other as negative, and manage them both via a function call which takes a positive or negative parameter and converts the negative to a positive value with the appropriate shifting action.  It looks as though the `rotl` function expects negative values to shift left — that's a reasonable but arbitrary choice.

Comment: …Now that the code is added to the question, it is easy to see that the version of `rotl()` at Wikipedia can only be called legitimately with a value of `shift` between 0 and 31 (if `unsigned int` is a 32-bit value). Any attempt to call it with a negative value leads to undefined behaviour. You've not shown where you get your examples using negative shifts — it doesn't seem to be Wikipedia. There could be an implementation of `rotl` that tests the value of `shift` for positive or negative and uses one or the other of the expressions shown in `rotl()` and `rotr()` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  - actually notes I was referring to showed directly answer - But I guess with your answer and other answer provided for modulo operation I understand what to do when value of shift is either of those two condition - thanks for the help

Comment: Note that there isn't a single "right answer" for dealing with negative shifts or shifts for more than the number of bits in the value type.  For rotation, it makes sense to treat the out-of-range shifts as a correct value modulo the number of bits; if you did the shifts one bit at a time, that's what you'd get.  But there are also valid reasons for treating it as an error (misuse of the function), and there are multiple possible treatments for the error.

Comment: fair enough - shall keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define CHAR_BITS  ( 8 )
#define UINT_BITS  ( sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BITS )

// We need modulo, not remainder. This is a way to obtain it.
int mod(int x, int m) {
    return ((x % m) + m) % m;
}

// Calculate left rotation for any shift value.
unsigned int rotl(unsigned int value, int shift) {
    int lshift = mod(shift, UINT_BITS);
    return (value << lshift) | (value >> (UINT_BITS - lshift));
}
```

Comment: So basically to get over the violation of condition shift greater than number of bits - we perform modulo operation to get the desired effect

Comment: Exactly. We stay in the allowed `shift` range but we correctly obtain the desired result.

Comment: That's the proposed solution; it is one valid way to deal with it.  Since the value of `UINT_BITS` will be a power of 2, you could probably use bit masking rather than a double modulus operation — though you have to be careful if you're willing to accept negative shifts.